# Как отреагировать на группу фото один раз?

Tags: python, циклы, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как пройти цикл один раз, чтобы если 2 фото разместить в группе телеграм, появился один текст, а не 2.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video', 'document'])
async def send_msg(message:types.Message):
    some_text = ['ключевое слово']
    for i in some_text:
        for i in range(1):
            if some_text:
                send = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Этот текст, видит пользователь, в группе.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), disable_notification=True, disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode='html')
                break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а тогда зачем вообще цикл?

Comment: Мне не нужно 5 или 10 раз, как все показывают, в видео и на сайтах.

Comment: Если не нужно несколько раз, то уберите циклы вообще, оставьте только отправку сообщения.

Comment: беглый взгляд - ничего что переменная `i` переопределяется после второго `for`?

Comment: Подскажите решение, как прописать, я новичок в пайтоне и все примеры, с интернета беру.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы один текст был, хоть 10 фото.

Comment: хотел узнать а вы с этими изображениями как-то работаете? Или важен сам факт отправки и картинки вы никуда не деваете?

Comment: Сам факт отправки, только одного текста, хоть от 10 фото.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем вот способ который вроде как работает, для того чтобы на фотки реагировало только 1 раз.

```
import random

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from asyncio import sleep
from time import time

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def get_foto(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if type(data.get('photo')) is list:
            data['photo'].append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
            data["time"] = time()
            return
        else:
            data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
            data["time"] = time()

    while time() - data["time"] < 3:
        await sleep(3)

    # в этот момент в data["photo"] лежат все фото которые мы получили, если что их можно куда-то переотправить
    some_text = ['ключевое слово']
    for i in some_text:
        for i in range(1):
            if some_text:
                send = await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Этот текст, видит пользователь, в группе.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), disable_notification=True, disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode='html')
                break
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        del data["time"]
        del data["photo"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Это не решение, мне нужно чтобы по ключевым словам работало и с этим все хорошо работает, а вот чтобы при отправке например 5-10 фото, был один текст в группе, а не 5 и не 10, по количество фото.

Comment: @tikeo Обновил_

Comment: Только ключевые слова, теперь не работают.

Comment: А как оно должно работать?

Comment: я буквально оставил ваш кусок кода с отправкой сообщения

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы в одном хендлере было, я пытался сделать так
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'video', 'document'])

И ругается на эту строку 'data['photo'] = [message.photo[-1].file_id]
нужно как то ее для текст сделать data['text'] = [message.text] и тут как то так if type(data.get('photo,'text')) is list: и тут примерно так del data["text"] 'но все равно не откликается на ключевые слова, я добавил отдельный хендлер и теперь работает.